# Swift Non Escaping Parameter

Tags: swift, xcode

i have a function that written in Swift 2. After i upgrade to Swift 3 now it gives me an warning "passing non escaping parameter success to function expecting an @escaping closure"

How i have to change my function to remove the warnings? this is my function:

```
func getOfficeDetail (_ officeID:Int, success: ([String:AnyObject]) -> (), failure: (NSError, [String:AnyObject]?) -> ()) -> Alamofire.Request {
    return self.GET ("/endpoint/\(officeID)", parameters : nil, success: success, failure: failure)
}
```

If i click the warning it give me prompt " Fix it Parameter "success" is implicitly non-escaping. And change the function to like this.

```
    func getOfficeDetail (_ officeID:Int, success: @escaping ([String:AnyObject]) -> (), failure: (NSError, [String:AnyObject]?) -> ()) -> Alamofire.Request {
    return self.GET ("/endpoint/\(officeID)", parameters : nil, success: success, failure: failure)
}
```

And the warning is still there. And if i click it just keep add the keyword @escaping after success.

This is my get function :

```
func GET (URL : String, parameters : [String : AnyObject]?, success: ([String:AnyObject]) -> (), failure: (NSError, [String:AnyObject]?) -> ()) -> Alamofire.Request {
//truncate
}
```

Comment: Show declaration of `GET`.

Comment: Update the question with GET function

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is actually that you are missing the `URL` parameter in your call to `GET`. `GET` is defined as `func GET (URL: String...)` but you have forgotten to say `URL:` in your call to `self.GET(...)`.

Then you need to give attention to your `GET` declaration. Is this compiling correctly without any `@escaping` parameters? If so, `getOfficeDetail` should compile with any `@escaping` parameters. Otherwise, they must match up. For example, if both parameters in `GET` are `@escaping`, both parameters in `getOfficeDetail` must be `@escaping`.